# Support Landscape and Portrait using StoryBoard in iOS Interface Builder

Tags: ios, storyboard, landscape-portrait

I am developed an application which supports both Portrait and Landscape orientation with the GPOrientationKit. I followed following link to do all the pages of the app to support both the orientations.

http://logisian.blogspot.in/

I did that app with XIB or NIB file. Now, I am currently working on an app with the storyboard. I don't know how to do the app which support both the orientations with the storyboard. GPOrientationKit worked well for XIB files. But I am struggling with storyboard.I need the functionality like GPOrientationKit with the storyboard.  Please help me to do that.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just add two subview to your mainView of your controller such as portraitView and landscape View, and toggle between those to as and when your orientation changes..I had something like this

In your viewWillAppear method add this

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

        if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation))
    {

//Keep LAndscape View Hidden
    self.portraitVIew.frame=self.view.frame;
    [self.view addSubview:self.portraitVIew];
    }else{


//Keep portrait View Hidden

    self.landscapeView.frame=self.view.frame;
    [self.view addSubview:self.landscapeView];
    }
    self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

     } 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(deviceOrientationDidChangeNotification:)
     name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
     object:nil];



}
```

and then implement the method deviceOrientationDidChangeNotification such as

```
- (void)deviceOrientationDidChangeNotification:(NSNotification*)note
{


        UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
        if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation))
        {
//Keep portrait View Hidden

            NSLog(@"YUP THIS IS LANDSCAPE");
            self.landscapeView.hidden=NO;
            self.landscapeView.frame=self.view.frame;
            [self.portraitVIew removeFromSuperview];
            ///self.landscapeView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);


            [self.view addSubview:self.landscapeView];
        }else {
//Keep LAndscape View Hidden

            self.landscapeView.hidden=YES;
            self.portraitVIew.frame=self.view.frame;
            NSLog(@"Portrait");

            [self.view addSubview:self.portraitVIew];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you click to project>select target > General you set the device Orientation.[image]